# Iphone Bluetooth device name

Tags: iphone

im using iphone sdk 3.1.2

Does anyone know how to programatically obtain the name of a Bluetooth device 
that is connected to the iphone. I am using Bluetooth in my app and want to 
display the name of the paired device ie if it was a Nokia BH-200 i can display this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the document *External Accessory Framework Reference*. That might allow you to do something but you'll have to play with it to see what values you can get from it. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi, i tried the External Accessory Framework but the connected acccessories method of the Accessory Manager always returns nil. I think this is because the bluetooth headset i have is a Nokia one.

Answer (score 0):

Your Nokia BH-200 is not a MFi verified accessory. It is only connected as A2DP/AVRCP/HFP/HSP. These are not related to MFi accessory communication. And iOS app cannot communicate with this pure Bluetooth device. It's not the problem of External Accessory Framework.